# How to use the same AngularJS controller across multiple MVC script files?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-material

I have created an MVC project and added AngularJS-Material and all required files.  I put the AngularJS App on the _Layout.cshtml page as I want to be able to display a toolbar throughout the project.

For each view I was planning on using a different controller but when I reference the controller in a new script file I get an error that says the controller is undefined.

The code below works fine and the only problems I get are when I try to add another view in the @RenderBody() section of the code. On each individual chstml file I am defining a new controller but keeping the same app.

Here is my layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="bPST" ng-controller="layoutCtrl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="~/Content/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="~/Ang_Scripts/bpst.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div layout="column" layout-fill>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Title </span>
            <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button ng-click="sideBarFunctions()">Menu</md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-sidenav ng-cloak class="md-sidenav-left md-whitefram-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-open="sideBarOpen">
        <div layout="column" layout-align="space-around stretch">
            <md-toolbar>
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">Menu</h2>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-content layout-padding layout="column" layout-align="start">
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
<hr />
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
</footer>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

login.js:

```
var bApp = angular.module('bPST', ['ngMaterial']);
bApp.controller('loginCTRL',function($scope) {

$scope.message = "Login";
});
```

Comment: I don't see `login.js` referenced in your code posted above - is that the issue?  I also question how you intend to construct the app.  When you say you want to "...add another view in the `@RenderBody()` are you talking about a Razor view?  If so, Angular tends to be used in Single Page Applications, wherein you would (in an ASP.NET MVC world) have a single Razor index view, and the rest of your application would be driven by Angular views.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was more with the way that I was creating the application in the js file.

I was doing this.

```
var bPSTApp = angular.module('bPST', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Then creating the controller like this.

```
bPSTApp.controller('layoutCtrl', function ($scope) {
//Add coding here

};
```

when I changed it up to this, it started working.

```
angular.module('bPST').controller('layoutCtrl', function ($scope) {
//Add coding here
});
```

Now all I need to do is reference the App in each controller file instead of trying to reference the variable that I was setting in the main JS file.

Also, since I am using the login.js on the login cshtml file, it was only being referenced in that view.

I do get that AngularJS and AngularJS Material is good for Single Page Applications, but there are functions that I want to use that make my application look good and function the way I want.

Got to love newbie mistakes.

Comment: Put all file js in your layout razor. It's more simple because your layout is shared between all page. If you use ngRouter or uiRouter, use partialview razor for page angular js. And when you configure your route, you need to add reference to controller angular. I hope your help.